# RFID (MFRC522) Scanner waiting to read or write Raspberry PI

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

Iam using PI 4 along with MFRC522 module with Python 3, inspite of proper connection, wiring and code shown in https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/ the python code to read or write does not detect when the RFID tag is moved closer to the scanner, code does not return any errors.

I also performed SPI loopback test and also checked the GPIO pins, both work fine. I tested the same module with Ardunio UNO and its able to read the tag.

Iam convinced that the issue is of the software not the hardware, If the issue is from the version compatibility, please help me out to resolve this issue.

Also iam using the latest version of Raspian OS which was installed on the SD Card, 2 days ago.

Comment: Please paste your code here in a formatted manner. Also, this question would be relevant to arduino stack exchange: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This Rpi SE Q&A might help: 
How can Rpi SPI python read the MFRC522 RFID / NFC module?
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/how-can-rpi-spi-python-read-the-mfrc522-nfc-module.